# Why isn't Android Studio's preview working for me?

Tags: android

I'm trying to follow the Android Developers site to build my first project up and going. I followed all of the instructions for creating a new project. The problem I'm running into is that I can't see the device preview. I have tried changing the device, cleaning and rebuilding, switching views, restarting Android Studio. [Image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rE61.png)

Comment: you can run the project?

Comment: can you run the project? :)

Comment: Yes. It seems like I can run it fine using the emulator. I get a little window that says 'no errors, no warnings,' and the app opens and displays 'Hello World!'

Answer (score 1):

change your android theme and android version........

see the picture below to make changes..I hope its help u.

[image]

Comment: The image is quite blurry. What theme am I supposed to select? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the developer settings on the device, follow these steps:-

**Step 1:** Go to the settings menu, and scroll down to "About phone." Tap it.

**Step2:** Scroll down to the bottom again, where you see "Build number/ Android Version."

**Step3:** Tap it seven (7) times (Build number) & thereafter reconnect your device.

That's all :)

Good luck & hope this helps.

Comment: Where do I find BIOS settings?

Comment: Try the above steps.